# Finding min, max, and avg of every N-values in a list

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python for data Analytics and I found a simple but unsolvable for me problem. I want to find min, max and average of every N-numbers in a list. And I am stuck on the best and fastest way to do it. Do I have to split the list on sublists and then  join the output or is there a faster way?

For example:
I have a list of

```
lst = [6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14]
```

and I want to find the min, max and avg of every 5 numbers and append them on seperatily lists like:

```
avg = [6.0, 9.4, 13.2]
min = [5.0, 8.0, 13.0]
max = [7.0, 11.0, 14.0]
```

Comment: How big is your input data?

Comment: I would suggest creating a function `groups` that lumps numbers in a list into groups of `n` length and then yields them up, creating a generator.

Comment: my input data has 400 values

Comment: Recommend you follow @Chris' advice and write a function `groups()` to return rolling groups of numbers of length n. Welcome to SO. On SO you're expected to try some code and post it. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Try to avoid using Python built-in `min` and `max` as the variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly:

Here is an example

```
lst = [6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14]

def Average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

new = [Average(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]
```

UPDATE: for all:

```
[[Average(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)], [max(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)], [min(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]]
```

however write them seperately ;)

Comment: Just define functions that accepts an input of a list ? Simply google function and swap out the function i my solution above. Try something like this for max: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-largest-number-in-a-list/

Comment: Also i generally good idea when talking speed to use comprehension

Comment: I think python also has inbuilt functions for this and numpy also. Try [max(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)] and [min(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]

Comment: My main problem was the way to slice 5 numbers step by step, thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for the example you gave:

```
lst = [6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14]

lavg = [sum(lst[i:i+5])/len((lst[i:i+5])) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]
lmin = [min(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]
lmax = [max(lst[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]

print(lavg)
print(lmin)
print(lmax)
```

output is :

```
[6.0, 9.4, 13.2]
[5, 8, 13]
[7, 11, 14]
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's need to calculate these data for sublists of length 5.

Comment: ok I edited it to answer the OP question

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way: find out the amount of "slices" your list contains, round it up to the bigger number, and then run a loop in range of this value, using incremented variable to assess the indexes of each slice. And within each iteration of the loop, apply the functions you need - `max()`, `min()` or whatever.

If needed, you can append them to the pre-created lists, or simply print them out, as you wish

```
lst = [6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14]
slices = round(len(lst) / 5)
slicer = 0
for i in range(slices):
    max_val = max(lst[slicer:slicer + 5])
    slicer +=5
    print(max_val)
```

Comment: The `range` function takes more than one parameter. Consider that `list(range(0, 15, 5))` will return `[0, 10, 15]`.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** I do not generally believe in offering answers for questions that show little effort, but other answers have been offered, and this one only builds on those existing answers.*

---

The other answers seem oriented toward iterating over groups of 5 elements for each stat you wish to accumulate.

For large datasets this will be inefficient. What if you want to generate them all on a single pass?

```
stats = [[], [], []]
for sublist in (lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)):
    stats[0].append(sum(sublist) / len(sublist))
    stats[1].append(min(sublist))
    stats[2].append(max(sublist))

stats = [tuple(stat) for stat in stats]
```

If we further wanted to generalize this, let's call the function `applyn` because it applies `n` functions to an iterable item and returns the results as a list of tuples.

```
def applyn(iter, *funs):
    results = [[] for _ in funs]
    for x in iter:
        for i, f in enumerate(funs):
            results[i].append(f(x))
    return [tuple(x) for x in results]
```

Now, we can write:

```
stats = applyn((lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)), 
               lambda x: sum(x) / len(x), 
               min, max)
```

And we get:

```
[(6.0, 9.4, 13.2), (5, 8, 13), (7, 11, 14)]
```